# Virtual machine in Azure not quite the same as a real machine

Tags: azure

Hope somebody could give me a hint?

When trying to use an Azure virtual machine to host a database I have problems with the hostname:port way to access the virtual machine instead of just hostname.
For example, I got a preview scadcam.cloudapp.net:51165 virtual machine. When I try to access the database hosted in there, my application thinks I´m trying to comunicate with the database thru this port.
Is there a way to define a url that does not show the port? Something like scadcam.cloudapp.net/51165  ?
I´m sure there are a lot of applications that may have this type of problem, so I suppose there is a way to do it?

Reagards

Comment: what do you mean by the "hostname:port" way to access the virtual machine?  What application is listening on EXTERNAL port 51165, which would be mapped to a potentially different internal port.  What is your application trying to communicate with that's running on the VM?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to host a database in a Virtual Machine, so I'm assuming you're trying to host an instance of SQL Server. If you want to connect to the hostname without having to specify the port you should start by doing the following:

- Create an unnamed instance in your SQL Server installation
- Add an endpoint for port 1433 to your virtual machine (see [this](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/how-to-guides/setup-endpoints/) link)

Also, if you're using .NET to connect to that database it's pretty easy to specify the port if you don't use port 1433:

```
Data Source=myserver.cloudapp.net,4999;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

In your question I also see that you're talking about scadcam.cloudapp.net:*51165*. Note that 51165 is probably the random port that is used for remote desktop, and you can't use that same port to connect to your database.